# Is there any way to block user navigation with out any prompt in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We have implemented our application navigation using react-router.

Is there any way to block user navigation(including forward,backward buttons) with out any prompt in react.

react-router history block subscribe function i can't use as it will throw default prompt. In my case i want to show my custom dialog.

Comment: You mean native browser back/forw?

Comment: yes. i want both navigations hsould be stopped on boolean. and they should not show any prompt. i want to show our own custom dialog for that.

Comment: That's not possible for security reasons

Comment: did you try `routerWillLeave` from react-router?

Comment: If you need to show custom prompt you can use     "react-router-navigation-prompt"

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener `popState` to freeze the navigation.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-navigation-freeze-9qpwt?file=/src/Home.js)

```js
const Home = ({ history }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const browserNavigationHandle = () =>
      window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", browserNavigationHandle);
    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", browserNavigationHandle);
  }, []);
  return <div>Home</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: but this seems to be tampering with history. Is there any legitimate way of doing this for large enterprise applications with out breaking any other standard functionality?

Comment: I think it's possible to use `history.replaceState` instead of `history.pushState`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to block a users browser navigation, as that would take away all control of a user and could be used in a very malicious way. What you can do though is stop your application from changing.

One way could be to listen to history changes and navigate back to the page the user should be on. Problem with that is will re-render and you might lose states, depending on your application.

Another way could be (as I havent tried this before) to use a customized history object. Check out how to setup the [Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router) with history. As seen in their example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

There might be a way to customize that history object so you can control its change and the applications response.

Answer (score 0):

To disable back button you can do below code in higher order component

```
componentDidMount() {
const { history } = this.props;

window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
  history.go(1);
});
```

}

but this component must be a `Route` component

Answer (score 0):

Just add `useHistory().go(1)` working for me.

Answer (score 0):

use this to prevent routing

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();}
```